# WebView2 Fixed Version not working when binaries stored on network share

Tags: winforms, webview2

I want to save the Fixed Version binaries on a network share path, but the WebView2 does not display the web page and does not throw an error.

I set the BrowserExecutableFolder path in the form designer:

```
    CoreWebView2CreationProperties1.BrowserExecutableFolder = "j:\Utilities\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.90.0.818.66.x64\"
    CoreWebView2CreationProperties1.Language = Nothing
    CoreWebView2CreationProperties1.UserDataFolder = Nothing
    Me.WebView21.CreationProperties = CoreWebView2CreationProperties1
    Me.WebView21.DefaultBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Me.WebView21.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.WebView21.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 25)
    Me.WebView21.Name = "WebView21"
    Me.WebView21.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 425)
    Me.WebView21.TabIndex = 6
    Me.WebView21.ZoomFactor = 1.0R
```

Setting to a UNC path, doesn't work  -
CoreWebView2CreationProperties1.BrowserExecutableFolder = "\UNCFile1\private\Utilities\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.90.0.818.66.x64"

Setting to the mapped drive, doesn't work  -
CoreWebView2CreationProperties1.BrowserExecutableFolder = "j:\Utilities\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.90.0.818.66.x64"

This will work -
CoreWebView2CreationProperties1.BrowserExecutableFolder = "C:\Utilities\Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.90.0.818.66.x64"

We run the application from a network share path instead of deploying to each users work station and would like to also store the fixed version binaries in the same network share path. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try setting th `UserDataFolder` to a local path ans see if that works. Then it might be that the user doesn't have write permission to the UNC path, which is the default path for `UserDataFolder`.

Comment: @PoulBak I tried setting the UserDataFolder to a local path but it does not work. In fact it throws this exception "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F)'" I am putting the files in UNC path and running the application so I do not believe it is a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#known-issues-for-fixed-version), according to Microsoft.

It seems WebView2's sandbox environement does not work (yet?) when launched from a network storage.

As an workarround, may disable sandbox using the [additional browser arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions.additionalbrowserarguments)    or set the environement variable `WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS` as `--no-sandbox` before webview initialization.

Sample code in Delphi:

```
SetEnvironmentVariable('WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS', '--no-sandbox');
EdgeBrowser.BrowserExecutableFolder := '\\unc\path\or\network\drive';
EdgeBrowser.CreateWebView;
```

Note, this might be a security risk in case if you will access untrusted websites.